# Найти совпадения в строках с ошибками

Tags: python, алгоритм, строки

Задача стоит следующим образом: есть два больших файла (более 100тыс. позиций) с почтовыми адресами. Один из них полностью на украинском языке и без ошибок. Во втором адреса могут быть как на русском, так и на украинском (как правило, отличия не существенные, однако бывают случаи, что один и тот же адрес звучит совсем по-разному, к примеру, просп. Победы -> просп. Перемоги) и могут быть разного рода ошибки (пропущены буквы или пробелы, опечатки). **Нужно найти совпадения.** 
Я рассматриваю два варианта:

1. Один раз исправить ошибки во втором файле при помощи какой-то базы данных всех улиц и переводчика и дальше сравнивать пословно (минус метода в том, что можно один раз исправить неправильно и потом программа всегда будет работать некорректно),
2. Использовать несколько разных алгоритмов для сравнения (сравнивать части слов, убрать гласные и тп).

---

Вопрос: какой вариант вы посоветуете? Или, возможно, есть более удачные решения таких проблем?

Comment: Первым делом найдите все совпадения без внесения изменений в файлы (приведите фрагменты файлов и вам помогут). По масштабу трагедии определитесь со следующими действиями. Они могут заключаться в наложение на данные для сравнения фильтров с помощью которых увеличивать число совпадений (пример - функция заменяющая по почтовому индексу адрес из некоторого источника адресов, например на одну область). Так исходные данные будут без изменений и вы будете контролировать процесс.

Comment: 1) Машинный перевод с рус. на укр. или наоборот (Гугл знает большое кол-во опечаток) - см., какое направление перевода даёт лучшие результаты и выбирайте 2) Опеределите шаблон адреса (какие слова в адресах повторяются? в каком контексте? может, перед/после него двойные пустые строки?...) и получите все совпадения с помощью регулярного выражения. С помощью Python PyPi `regex` / R `adist` можно найти fuzzy matches. 4) Возможно сравнить каждый адрес с адресами из другого файла с помощью расстояния Левенштейна (в РНР - [`levenshtein`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.levenshtein.php)).